# Text in Span overflows Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have some text I append to a div and then apply the [Boxfit jquery plugin](https://github.com/michikono/boxfit) on it.  That creates a `<span>` within the parent div.  This then allows the text to overflow, eventhough before the `<span>` is created, it works fine.  I've tried:

1. Adding overflow to the span
2. Adding heigh/width to the span that inhereits
3. Adding overflow to the `<div>`'s parent `<div>` but this messes up my jquery ui handles for resize
4. Changeing the display from the default `table-cell` to `block` and `inline-block`

I don't know exactly how to proceed, so any help on this would be awesome.  I'm trying to use height inheritance and display/posiiton changes, but nothing so far.  Thanks!  Here is the code:

CSS:

```
.text-block
{
    cursor: default;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="template-1of3X template-droppable ui-resizable text review ui-draggable font-oxygen selected" style="top: 351px; width: 256px; height: 151px; position: absolute; left: 27px;">
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1000; display: block;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000; display: block;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1000; display: block;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1000; display: block;"></div>
<div class="text-block" style="display: table;">
<span class="boxfitted" style="display: table-cell; font-size: 14px;">One whiff and you know this is serious stuff. The aromas of baking brioche, coconut, candied citrus and leather pick up roasted coffee and grilled nuts on the palate, permeating the senses. Profound depth and complexity, offering a unique Champagne experience. Drink now through 2006. 40,000 cases made. –BS</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle, with the boxfit plugin as an external resource? This will help others test it out easier

Comment: I tried to recreate it but am not seeing the spill over http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/MCPct/1/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using other CSS operators such as:

```
white-space:pre; /* or pre-wrap - Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks. */

word-wrap:break-word; /* this allows unbreakable words to be broken. */

text-wrap:unrestricted; /* Lines may break between any two characters? */
```

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
.text-block span 
{
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
    overflow:inherit;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    /*position:inherit;*/
}
```

and that seemed to take care of everything.  Thanks for the help though!